# Postgresql rules and returning clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm new to Postgresql and I'm digging into its features.
An update/delete rule with a conditional "do instead nothing" seems to break the "returning clause" for every update/delete query.
Is there any solution to this as of postgresql 9.5?

Here the simple sql snippet I run for testing:

```
-- clear && dropdb --if-exists graph && createdb graph -E UTF8 -T template0 && psql graph < schema.sql

create table vertices (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    hash char(32),
    label varchar(128) not null,
    data jsonb default '{}'
);

-- default groups and users cannot be updated or deleted --
create or replace rule preventDefaultVtxUpdate as
    on update to vertices
    where ( old.label in ('group', 'user') and old.data->>'name' in ('superadmin', 'guest') )
    do instead nothing;

create or replace rule preventDefaultVtxDelete as
    on delete to vertices
    where ( old.label in ('group', 'user') and old.data->>'name' in ('superadmin', 'guest') )
    do instead nothing;

-- default groups and users
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('group', '{"name":"superadmin"}');
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('group', '{"name":"guest"}');

insert into vertices (label, data) values ('user', '{"name":"superadmin"}');
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('user', '{"name":"guest"}');

-- try
update vertices set data = '{}' returning *;
delete from vertices returning *;
```

It yells:

```
ERROR:  cannot perform UPDATE RETURNING on relation "vertices"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.
ERROR:  cannot perform DELETE RETURNING on relation "vertices"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.
```

EDIT WITH CURRENT SOLUTION:
As commented, I solved rewriting rules as triggers. It's uglier but works.
Any performance implication in using the following triggers instead of rules?

```
create table vertices (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    hash char(32),
    label varchar(128) not null,
    data jsonb default '{}'
);

create or replace function preventDefaultVtxUpdateAndDelete() returns trigger AS $preventDefaultVtxUpdateAndDelete$
    begin
        return null;
    end
$preventDefaultVtxUpdateAndDelete$ language plpgsql;

create trigger preventDefaultVtxUpdateAndDelete
    before update or delete on vertices
    for each row
        when ( old.label in ('group', 'user') and old.data->>'name' in ('superadmin', 'guest') )
        execute procedure preventDefaultVtxUpdateAndDelete();

-- default groups and users
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('group', '{"name":"superadmin"}');
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('group', '{"name":"guest"}');

insert into vertices (label, data) values ('user', '{"name":"superadmin"}');
insert into vertices (label, data) values ('user', '{"name":"guest"}');

    insert into vertices (label, data) values ('user', '{"name":"ciao"}');

-- try
select * from vertices;
update vertices set data = '{}' returning *;
delete from vertices returning *;
select * from vertices;
```

Comment: You could always try to implement rule behaviour in triggers.

Comment: The use or rules is discouraged because of such limitations and the uncontrollable side effects it can cause. As suggested by Consider Me, use triggers instead.

Comment: Any performance implication in using the following triggers instead of rules?